# How to make tabs align center in Tabs Responsive of WordPress?

Tags: css, wordpress, tabs, responsive, center

I use Elementor in WordPress to develop a website that i use a plugin 'Tabs Responsive' to make the tabs.
I want to align the tab to center. The Tabs Responsive has Custom CSS section but I try many code it wont work for me. My tab short code is [TABS_R id=233]. Any help would be appreciated. From [1] to [2].
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VvCYg.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RUPKk.png

Comment: Short code is not enough. Send me the URL and I can help you.

Comment: Just add: `#tab_container_233 .wpsm_nav-tabs { display: flex; justify-content: center; }` in your custom CSS. https://nimb.ws/1tRvVn